# How to delete last n rows from Numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to delete the last few rows from a numpy array. I'm able to delete 0 to i rows with the following code.

```
for i, line in enumerate(two_d_array1):
    if all(v == 0 for v in line):
        pass
    else:
        break

two_d_array2 = np.delete(two_d_array1, slice(0, i), axis=0)
```

Any suggestions on how to do the same for the end of the array?

```
for i, line in enumerate(reversed(two_d_array2)):
    if all(v == 0 for v in line):
        pass
    else:
        break

two_d_array3 = np.delete(two_d_array2, **slice(0, i)**, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [slice](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Indexing.html#Slices) notation for your indexing.

To remove the last `n` rows from an array:

```
a = np.array(range(10)).reshape(5, 2)
>>> a
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7],
       [8, 9]])

n = 2  # Remove last two rows of array.
>>> a[:-n, :]
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5]])
```

To remove the first `n` rows from an array:

```
>>> a[n:, :]  # Remove first two rows.
array([[4, 5],
       [6, 7],
       [8, 9]])
```

Answer (score 0):

*you can also use :*
array_name[:-n]
This is the efficient approach with best time complexity than the previous one